# Calculating an Intensity Centroid

Tags: calculus, computer-science, image-processing, centroid

I am trying to understand the theory behind calculating an Intensity Centroid (image processing), in particular defining moments.

As defined by Rosin [1](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Paul.Rosin/corner2.pdf):

$m_{pq}=\underset{x,y}{\Sigma}x^py^qI(x,y)$

From what I assume/understand:

$x$ and $y$ are the $x$ $y$ co-ordinates of a pixel.

$p$ and $q$ are order of moments for a pixel (a weighted average of pixel intensity) - not sure how these are calculated.

Is it a case of the $Ix$ and $Iy$ both determine the values of $p$ and $q$ respectively?

As you can no doubt tell I have no math background, if anyone could help explain this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't calculate p and q we specify them. For example for the moment of order 2 we set p and q=2. I(x,y) is just a function of intensity and is not used to calculate p or q however it is used to calculate m_pq

Comment: OK that helps somewhat, thanks. How would you determine what value to set for the moment of order?

Comment: It depends. Each moment gives different information, letting p=q=0 would give the sum of the intensity. p=q=1 gives  a value that gives more weighting to distance.

Comment: Just one last question, in the Rosin paper am I correct is stating that p = 0 and q = 1?